# Adding a list of features to a product via the product's cms page

Tags: cms, list-view

I want to display a list of product features on a product page via the Magento Product Information panel without using any HTML.

What's the best way customize the panel to let me do what I'm showing in the picture below. A plug-in or extension that you can recommend is a perfectly suitable answer.

[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase this please? Like this it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

From that you are asking it appears that you could just use the WYSIWYG editor. Click on the WYSIWYG editor under the text field and then use the "Insert/Remove Bulleted List" feature.

When you are done editing click submit and save the product.